# Zend OpenId Consumer storage Cannot access storage directory

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, openid

I have an application developed in Zend Framework 1.11.  I use Zend_OpenId to create a single sign on with partner websites.  This has been functioning fine until I upgraded my version of PHP to 5.3.13.  I now get the error stated below:

```
Error: Cannot access storage directory /root/tmp/
```

I have tracked this down to Zend_OpenId_Consumer_Strorage_File.  The temp directory is getting set by getenv('TMP') which returns /root/tmp.  If i override this by hard coding the tmp directory to /tmp my OpenId SSO app works again.

I have a second server which the app works on, but it is running an earlier version of PHP 5.3.  Testing getenv('TMP') returns false on that server, so Zend looks in /tmp.

Is it possible to either:

a) Override the storage directory in Zend?
b) Disable getenv on the server running 5.3.13 so that it returns false and so Zend looks in /tmp and not /root/tmp?

Comment: Override constructor so you will have consistent behaviour. Do not hardcode into framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aurimas for his comment.  For those of you interested in the answer who may have a similar problem I have overridden the constructor:

```
$dir = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer_Storage_File('/tmp');
$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer($dir);
```